# CarrierWave can't download an image - CarrierWave::IntegrityError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm trying to download this [image](http://www.epibrasil.com.br/product.ashx?Protetor%20auditivo%20sem%20Cord%C3%A3o&p0=131abdcc-3b44-4322-bc1b-46c23c9c61b9&pw=1000&ph=1000&p1=.jpg) using CarrierWave but it keeps giving this exception:

```
CarrierWave::IntegrityError
```

My download works for many images, but it's not working for this particular domain.

I've looked at this [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/CarrierWave/IntegrityError) but it didn't say too much.

Here's my whitelist:

```
%w(jpg jpeg gif png)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `CarrierWave::IntegrityError` is raised when trying to download images that are not on the extension whitelist or are on the extension blacklist.

You can check out the [CarrierWave specs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/c2ee2e89d3aa447c6b81186be6d627202d33a97f/spec/mount_spec.rb) for tests that induce the `IntegrityError`. This should help you figure out why your code is raising the error.

Comment: But look at this link http://www.epibrasil.com.br/product.ashx?Protetor%20auditivo%20sem%20Cord%C3%A3o&p0=131abdcc-3b44-4322-bc1b-46c23c9c61b9&pw=1000&ph=1000&p1=.jpg and that my whitelist %w(jpg jpeg gif png) . I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: If the white and black lists are OK, is there anything else different about the images that upload successfully and the one that doesn't?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to find out :)

Comment: Yep sorry :). Okay one other suggestion. I notice you have a ã symbol in the file name. Looks like CarrierWave only whitelists English letters, arabic numerals and '-+_.' symbols by default. Perhaps that is why your image is erroring?

Comment: Well, i've tried other images without symbols and doesn't work as well =/